# regex for password that does not allow \ symbol

Tags: regex

Hello friends i am creating regex for password

here is my regex

```
    /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[0-9~=?<>()`'"\/& ]).{8,20}.*$/
```

password should:

1. Be between 8-20 characters
2. It must include at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter
3. It also may include symbols but not these: `=?<>()'"/\&`.

my regex is ok but it accept \ symbol. But i dont allow this symbol so please suggest some solution.

Comment: And why didn't you add your symbol to the list of excluded ones ?

Comment: You can use: `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[\\0-9~=?<>()`'"\/& ]).{8,20}.*$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been cautioned recently on this so placing my code in comment as answer.

This regex should work:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[\\0-9~=?<>()'"\/& ]).{8,20}$/
```

Comment: Maybe the downvote is for not pointing out the other error(s) in the OP's regex.  Like for example the final `.*` that nullifies the upper limit set by `.{8,20}`.  And for not asking which "symbols" he wants to allow.  Depending on the regex flavor and system settings, that could include a lot of things he probably isn't expecting.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Thanks and I really appreciate your detailed comment. I didn't pay attention to presence of `.*` in OP's regex since question was about allowing an additional backslash. (Edited now).